# If a linear map, $φ: U→V$ is bijective, then $φ(x)=0$ has only the solution $x=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If a linear map, $φ: U→V$ is bijective, then $φ(x)=0$ has only the solution $x=0$.

"an attempt":

$$φ(0)=φ(0\cdot x)=φ(0)+φ( x)$$

Comment: I do not see any attempt... could you please be more precise... what you have done does not say anything about $x=0$..

Comment: This question was asked and answered some minutes ago.

Comment: linear map that is bijective means that its kernel is zero, hence the only solution for $\phi$(x)=0 is $x=0$

Comment: so what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $φ(0)=0$ because $φ(0)=φ(0*0)=φ(0)+φ(0)=>φ(0)=0$. Now suppose that there is $0\neq x\in U$ such that $φ(x)=0$. Then $φ$ is not bijective.

Comment: Unless you change that * there for a +, that could be a rather misleading line...

Answer (score 0):

The assumption that the map is linear is redundant. It is the DEFINITION of bijective map between sets that $\phi(x)=y$ has exactly one solution for every $y$ in the range.

Comment: You need linearity to conclude that the unique $x$ such that $\phi(x) = 0$ is $x = 0$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese linearity is much too strong, you just observe that $\phi(0) =0.$ Basically, I think this is a poorly phrased exercise, which was the gist of my answer.

Comment: Without linearity, $\phi$ is an arbitrary bijection so there is no reason why $\phi(0)$ must be $0$. For example, $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\phi(x) = x + 1$ is a bijection, so there is a unique $x$ such that $\phi(x) = 0$, but $x \neq 0$.